# Ubuntu 18.04 use top panel for program like in old version

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-gnome, interface

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to use window top panel for program's panel (Global app menu). In older versions (16.04, 14.04), by default this panel was used to together with program panel. But now they are separated (example in the screenshot).

How can I use top panel on Ubuntu 18.04 like in old version?

[image]

Comment: Install gnome tweak tools. From there you can select some of the options you need. Install dash to panel gnome extension. Both these can be easily installed from Ubuntu Software. simply search for "gnome tweak" and "dash to panel"

Comment: @PRATAP I want to use global app menu but by tweak tools unfortunately i can't customize this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use **Unity 7.5** in Ubuntu 18.04. When you login click the "gear" next to the <kbd>Sign In</kbd> button and select `Unity` from the drop down menu:

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 five desktops]

If you did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 the Unity desktop option will be missing. You can [install it](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/) using:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

You will be prompted if you want to change the login screen to the old Unity format of `lightdm`:

- If you want Unity like login screen: select `lightdm`
- If you want to keep the default login screen in Ubuntu 18.04: select `gdm3`

Comment: Yes, it resolve my problem but on 18.04 unity has some annoying bags. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a unity like behaviour back by installing this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/